# Autodesk Forge Datamanagement API: No "extension.type" found in payload

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am trying to upload a file by using the ["POST projects/:project_id/storage"](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-storage-POST/): "Creates a storage location in the OSS where data can be uploaded to."

I retrieved the projectId and folderId where I want to create a storage location for the file "vaac_RevBlockImperial.dwg". I created this curl-call:

```
curl
 -X POST
 -H "Authorization: Bearer 3-legged-token-with-data:create-scope" 
 -H "Accept: application/vnd.api+json" 
 -H "Content-Type: application/vnd.api+json" 
"https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/a.cGVyc30uYWw6dWUyOTNmYmU0I0QyMDE2MDUwOTMxNzU3Mjgx/storage" 
 -d "{"""data""": {"""type""": """object""", """attributes""": {"""name""": """vaac_RevBlockImperial.dwg"""}, """relationships""": { """target""": {"""data""": { """type""": """folders""", """id""": """urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.z9LUCe1_QoKWT8VFukdc9Q""" }}}}}"
```

As a result, I get following response:

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
},
"errors": [{
    "id": "2919a501-a362-46c4-a441-03fefcacb7b2",
    "status": "400",
    "code": "BAD_INPUT",
    "title": "One or more input values in the request were bad",
    "detail": "No \"extension.type\" found in payload."
}]
}
```

What does "detail": "No \"extension.type\" found in payload." mean?

Answer (score 2):

Your payload contains an invalid type, i.e. it should be "type:objects" instead of "type:object".

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer. That led me to an online [JSON-validator](http://jsonschemalint.com/draft5/) where I validated the body against its definition. As a result, I found that the body was missing

```
"jsonapi": {
    "version": "1.0"
  },
```

and in the attributes-part, "extension" was required:

```
"extension" : {
  "type": "myType",
  "version": "myVersion",
  "schema": { "href": "myReference" }
  }
```

This gave me the next JSon-body for a "POST projects/:project_id/storage"-call:

```
{
    "jsonapi": {
        "version": "1.0"
    },
    "data": {
        "type": "object",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "myfile.jpg",
            "extension": {
                "type": "myType",
                "version": "myVersion",
                "schema": {
                    "href": "myReference"
                }
            }
        },
        "relationships": {
            "target": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "folders",
                    "id": "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.mgS-lb-BThaTdHnhiN_mbA"
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Which gave me another error when posting, but the JSon was accepted. It seems the given example(s) weren't updated to the latest definition.

Comment: for this case, the "objects" fix should be enough, you don't need to pass the extension type (as of now).

Answer (score 0):

Quick update following the answers already provided in this thread.
The online documentation & tutorial were updated to reflect those answers:
https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.